# How to add a scroll view to the existing view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, controller, scrollview

I have added a lot of ui elements in my controller and I have also done the web service part in the implementation code. It seems like my default screen size view controller is not sufficient for me to display the information. Is it possible to add a scroll view to the existing controller and if yes please give an idea or an example, so that I can add some more ui elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to make the main view a scrollview:

```
- (void)loadView {
    // create and configure the scrollview
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.view = scrollView;
}
```

`loadView` is the method where the subclassed View Controllers should configure their main view, it is called automatically before the VC loads and shouldn't be called directly.

After adding all the elements to the scrollview you want to change the content size so it actually scrolls with something like this:

```
// this for a horizontal scroll
[scrollView setContetSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetMaxX(lastElementOnTheRight), scrollView.frame.size.height)];

// this for a vertical scroll
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrolView.frame.size, CGRectGetMaxY(lastElementOnTheBottom))];
```

Comment: OMGGGGG Thank you soooo much man, I just found a solution to one of my problems in your code. Thanks a loooooooooot!!! (Wow after 5 years) Have a good day sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the view you want to add to scroll view and then go to edit->embed in->scroll view.

Comment: Scroll view is disabled and more over it is located in editor but not in edit.

Comment: oh yeah. hehe. why is it disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the scrolling behavior by default in a view Controller through inheritance.  You may find this diagram helpful for future reference: [uikit classes](http://iosdevelopmenttutorials.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/uikit_classes.jpg).

Additionally,  you can add a scrollview to a view as such:

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: It didn't worked not even the scroller, I was able see.